# Dynamic day and time field according to Number of lectures in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I want to create dynamic fields (input :day and time) according to Number of lectures a tutor takes.

For e.g : If there is only one lecture per week, then a dropdown for a day input  and two input type time will be created for timings from to like 2.00pm to 3:00 pm. For 2 lectures per week first day input then two time input followed by second day input and two time input.

I tried using jquery and its working but that was little complex by and using jquery with angular 'not a good idea.'

I Tried :

```
<fieldset style="display:none;" class="slot" >
        <div ng-repeat="i in days | limitTo:-lectures">

            <label>{{$index+1}}
                <span>Select Day : </span>
                <span>
                <select ng-model="day" ng-options="x for x in days" ng-blur="sendTiming()"></select>
                </span>
            </label>

            <label>Select Duration
                <span >
                    <p id='datepair{{$index + 1}}' name='datepair{{$index + 1}}' class='datepair' data-language='javascript'>
                        <input type='text' class='time start' name='timefrom[{{$index + 1}}]' id='timefrom{{$index + 1}}' ng-model="fromtime[]" required ng-blur="sendTiming()" ng-value=""/> to 
                        <input type='text' class='time end' id='timeto{{$index + 1}}' name='timeto[{{$index + 1}}]' ng-model="totime" required ng-blur="sendTiming()" ng-value=""/>
                    </p>
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Any idea is welcome.
Thanks

EDIT: here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8btsqbnu/

Comment: The forum can not help you to solve your problem statement. You need to show what have you tried so far and we will assist you further from there! Show us the progress you have done and where you stuck?

Comment: Currently, how do you know whether there is one lecture per week or two lecture per week? Is it something user enters. Currently, fiddle just show a select control with 2 input controls, which is for one lecture per week.

Comment: No it will be fetched from server that means it will be dynamic. In fiddle I put dumpy data.

Comment: So you get number of lecture from backend. If you get 2 lectures you have to show a select control with 2 input controls right?

Comment: Two lectures (first slot) - 1 input for day, 2 inputs for time. and on pressing Add More replicate the above inputs for second slot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[plucker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CofovD6IOzHRVvyI3IG6?p=preview)

It adds 1 input for day, 2 inputs for time for each button click.

you need to have a directive with isolated scope to dynamically add controls

```
.directive("lectureTimings", function(){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
      days : '=',
      timing: '='
    }, 
    templateUrl:'timings.html'
  }
})
```

Directive template

```
<select ng-model="timing.day" ng-options="x for x in days" ng-blur="sendTiming()"></select>
<br/>
<input ng-model="timing.from"/>to<input ng-model="timing.to"/>
```

Main controller template

```
 <input type="button" name="addmore" class="addmore" ng-click="addTiming();" value="Add Classes"/>

  <div ng-repeat= "timing in timingsData">
    <br/>
  <lecture-timings  timing="timing" days="days"></lecture-timings>
 </div>
```

each time user click button

We push new object to timingsData and ng-repeat will automatically repeat

```
$scope.addTiming = function(){

    $scope.timingsData.push({
     day:'',
     from: '',
     to: ''
   });
}
```

Comment: Hey Ravi thank you for your response. From the plunker : how will I be able to create dynamic field "It adds 1 input for day, 2 inputs for time for each button click." creates only once. I want it dynamic according to number of lectures.

Comment: In plucker, each time you click button it is adding new set for controls right? you saying,  "creates only once"

Comment: It is creating only 1 slot, I need no of slots according to no of lectures.(One slot means 1 input for day and two input for timings).

Comment: You are saying that if you get lecture count as 1 from backend you have to display 1 slot, if you get lecture count as 2 then you have to display 2 slots right?

Comment: Yes, by the way I did that by changing some code in your plunker. Thanks I was stucked in this from 2days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124415/discussion-between-deepika-and-ravi-teja).